# How do I make a content in HTML?

Tags: html

So I've tried googling it but no help at all. What I want to make is "#history" go to the section where it says History. My code:
`<a href="#history"> History </a>`
Any help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an id on the element and add #id to the url.

Example:

```
<a id="example">Hello</a>
```

https://url.com#example

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example:

```css
section {
display:block;
height: 200px;
background-color: #000000;
color: white;
width: 100%;
}

#history {
background-color: blue;
color: yellow;
}

a {
background-color: red;
display: block;
padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section id="history">History Section</section>
<section>Click Button at bottom of these sections</section>
<section>Click Button at bottom of these sections</section>
<section>Click Button at bottom of these sections</section>
<section>Click Button at bottom of these sections</section>
<section>Click Button at bottom of these sections</section>
<section>Click Button at bottom of these sections</section>
<section>Click Button at bottom of these sections</section>
<section>Click Button at bottom of these sections</section>
<section>Click Button at bottom of these sections</section>
<section>Click Button at bottom of these sections</section>

<a href="#history"><button>Go to History Section</button></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the id value on the element where you want to go to History section.

Use the id value to on the href tag to go to that section. Check the code snippet

```html
<a href=#history_section>Go to History</a>








<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>


<div>
lorem ipsum<br>
lorem ipsum<br>
lorem ipsum<br>
lorem ipsum<br>
lorem ipsum<br>
lorem ipsum<br>
lorem ipsum<br>
lorem ipsum<br>
lorem ipsum<br>
</div>





<ul>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum<li>
  <li>lorem ipsum<li>
  <li>lorem ipsum<li>
  <li>lorem ipsum<li>
<ul>












<div>
<h4>History section lorem ipsum</h4>
<p id="history_section">lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```